# Transforming an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, compression

I watched [a presentation by Dave Thomas on Elixir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hDVftaPQwY) where he gave an example problem that he solved using functional programming. He mentioned using Ruby to solve the same problem, but did not show an example. I decided to give it a try. The problem goes something like this:

For a list (Ruby doesn't have lists, but for our purposes an Array is close enough) of *n* numbers, create a new list where unique numbers are represented once, and repeated numbers are represented by a tuple (again, Ruby doesn't have tuples, but for our purposes a Hash or an Array would do) where the first element is the number itself, and the second is its count.

For Example, the following list:

```
[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6 ]
```

Would become:

```
[ 1, {2, 3}, 3, {4, 2}, 5, {6, 3} ]
```

I came up with the following solution.

```
list = [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6 ]
list.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n, hash| hash[n] += 1 }.map { |k, v| v > 1 ? { k => v } : k }
#=> [ 1, {2 => 3}, 3, {4 => 2}, 5, {6 => 3} ]
```

How would you go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- From the moment you write `hash[n] += 1`, your solution is not functional anymore.
- `each_with_object` is also imperative, for FP you should use `reduce`.
- `reduce` works well with linked lists, not so well for generating new arrays. In any case, `reduce` is a generic abstraction, there is a more specific one to the problem at hand: [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk).

That's how I'd write it:

```
xs.chunk(&:itself).map { |y, ys| ys.size == 1 ? y : {y => ys.size} }
```

Comment: Thanks great. I am wondering about `&:itself`, there's no mention of it in [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html). Is that a shortcut or a keyword?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-itself

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I was looking at Enumerable. So I suppose `&:itself` translates to `chunk { |n| n.itself }`, also the same as `chunk { |n| n }`

Comment: @Mohamad that is correct, and by extension `&:any_method` is translated the same way

Comment: @tokland I'm wondering, what makes this `hash[n] += 1` not functional? Is it because I'm telling the program to "add 1"?

Comment: Immutability is a key concept of functional programming. You can't change anything in-place (add, update, remove, and so on). http://goo.gl/4OyjP

Answer (score 1):

I would write a slower but easier to read version:

```
def same_or_tuple(list)
    list.map {|x| if list.count(x) == 1 then x
                  else [x, list.count(x)] end}
        .uniq
end
```